# Django AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to reach this format in my output:

```
{  
    "E": [  
         {  
             "value": 50,  
             "label": "company1"  
         },  
         {  
             "value": 0,  
             "label": "company2"  
         },  
         ...  
    ],  
    "P": [  
         {  
             "value": 50,  
             "label": "company1"  
         },  
         {  
             "value": 0,  
             "label": "company2"  
         },  
         ...  
    ],  
    "C": [  
         {  
             "value": 50,  
             "label": "company1"  
         },  
         {  
              "value": 0,  
              "label": "company2"  
         },  
         ...  
    ],  
  }  
}
```

so I decide to use serializers.DictField (dictionary field)
but I have got this error when I run my api ('QuerySet' object has no attribute 'items')
after search in net I could not find suitable description for solving this problem. I guess
query filter in     my model methods cause the issue and queryset does not have items for iterating.
on the other hand first I write these model methods in jupyter separately and they worked correctly.

[image: My Model Methed Test:]

### Details of my code:

***Model***:

```
`class TblCorporation(models.Model):  
    contractcorporationid = models.AutoField(db_column='ContractCorporationID', primary_key=True)   
    contractid = models.ForeignKey(TblContract, related_name="Contract_Corporation",  
                                   on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='ContractID')  
    companyid = models.ForeignKey(TblCompany, related_name="Company_Corporation",   
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='CompanyID')  
    e_percent = models.FloatField(db_column='E_Percent')  
    p_percent = models.FloatField(db_column='P_Percent')  
    c_percent = models.FloatField(db_column='C_Percent')  
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:  
        return '%s: e=%s, p=%s, c=%s' % (self.companyid.company, self.e_percent,   
                                         self.p_percent, self.c_percent)  
  
    def E(self):  
        e = TblCorporation.objects.filter(contractid__exact=self.contractid).values(  
            'companyid__company', 'e_percent').annotate( value = F('e_percent'),  
                                                        label = F('companyid__company')).values(  
                                                        'value', 'label')  
        return (e)  
    
    def P(self):  
        p = TblCorporation.objects.filter(contractid__exact=self.contractid).values(  
            'companyid__company', 'p_percent').annotate( value = F('p_percent'),  
                                                        label = F('companyid__company')).values(  
                                                        'value', 'label')  
        return (p)  
  
    def C(self):  
        c = TblCorporation.objects.filter(contractid__exact=self.contractid).values(  
            'companyid__company', 'c_percent').annotate( value = F('c_percent'),  
                                                        label = F('companyid__company')).values(  
                                                        'value', 'label')    
        return (c)  
  
    def company(self):  
        return self.companyid.company  
    
    class Meta:  
        db_table = 'tbl_Corporation'  
        verbose_name = 'Contract_Corporation'  
        verbose_name_plural = 'Contract_Corporations' `
```

***Serializer:***

```
`class EPCDictField(serializers.DictField):  
    def to_internal_value(self, data):  
        # Perform validation on the keys of the dictionary here  
        if set(data.keys()) != {"value", "label"}:  
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Invalid keys for dictionary.")  
        return super().to_internal_value(data)  
    
    def to_representation(self, value):  
        return super().to_representation(value)  
        
class ContractCorporationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):  
    E = EPCDictField()  
    P = EPCDictField()  
    C = EPCDictField()  
 
    class Meta:  
        model = TblCorporation  
        fields = ('E', 'P', 'C')`
```

***API:***

```
`def get_ContractCorporation(request, id):  
    try:  
        contractCorporations = TblCorporation.objects.filter(contractid__exact=id)  
        serializer = ContractCorporationSerializer(contractCorporations, many=True)  
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)  
    except Exception as e:  
        return Response({"status": "error", "data": str(e)},  
                         status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `E`, `P` and `C` don't return dictionaries, hence that will not work. But the good news is: we don't need these, we can just make a serializer for one item:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    label = serializers.CharField()
    value = serializers.FloatField()


class ContractCorporationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    E = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    P = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    C = ItemSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TblCorporation
        fields = ('E', 'P', 'C')
```

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Tbl` prefix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

Comment: thank you ver much williem it solve the problem, but why my model methods couldn't retuen dictionaries? they return a queryset in jupyter when I test them

Comment: my models have Tbl perfix because I create them from an existing db by inspectdb command.

Comment: @AliSajadian: these are `QuerySet`s, `.values()` makes it a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, but *not* a list, so nothing the `DictField` itself can "chew".